# Iphone/iPad local asp files?

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, uiwebview

I already know that you can load local html files in a UIWebView, but could you do the same thing with asp files? And could you use AJAX on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

ASP is a **server-side language**, meaning that it gets executed on the server. There isn't an ASP server installed on the iPhone. So no, you cannot execute ASP scripts on the iPhone.

Yes, you can use Ajax on the iPhone so long as the files are in the document sandbox.